# RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord, disnake

Я бы хотел, что бы мой дискорд бот  отправлял сообщения от своего лица, НО у меня выводится ошибка, когда я на стадии отправки сообщения:

```
import disnake
import threading
import asyncio
from disnake.ext import commands
from threading import Thread

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=disnake.Intents.all())
client = disnake.Client()

ask_ls = ['Что выберете:', '1. Написать сообщение.', '2.Выйти']
ls_write = ['1']
ls_exit = ['2']

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Ready')

async def asks():
    print('\n'.join(ask_ls))
    for ask in ask_ls:
        choose = input('#>')
        if choose in ls_write:
            # try:
            channel = await bot.fetch_channel(int(input("ID Канала: ")))
            await channel.send(content=input("Ваше сообщение: "))  # На этом этап получаю ошибку, когда нажимаю отправить
            # except:
            #     return await asks()
        elif choose in ls_exit:
            exit()
        else:
            return await asks()

def between_callback():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    loop.run_until_complete(asks())
    loop.close()

def main():
    print('Много команд')

th1 = Thread(target=main).start()
th2 = Thread(target=between_callback).start()
```

И ещё когда я хочу выйти из программы, то она не на что не реагирует и больше не даёт писать что то. Как мне всё это исправить?

Ошибки:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2 (between_callback):
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File
"C:\Users\maksi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\
threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File 
"C:\Users\maksi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\
threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\maksi\PycharmProjects\DS-BOT\main.py", line 66, in 
between_callback
    loop.run_until_complete(asks())
  File 
"C:\Users\maksi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\
asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\maksi\PycharmProjects\DS-BOT\main.py", line 52, in 
asks
    channel = await bot.fetch_channel(input(f"[{current_date} 
{time.strftime('%X')}] ID Канала: "))
  File "C:\Users\maksi\PycharmProjects\DS-BOT\venv\lib\site- 
packages\disnake\client.py", line 2210, in fetch_channel
    data = await self.http.get_channel(channel_id)
  File "C:\Users\maksi\PycharmProjects\DS-BOT\venv\lib\site- 
packages\disnake\http.py", line 342, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as 
response:
  File "C:\Users\maksi\PycharmProjects\DS-BOT\venv\lib\site- 
packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\maksi\PycharmProjects\DS-BOT\venv\lib\site- 
packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 467, in _request
    with timer:
  File "C:\Users\maksi\PycharmProjects\DS-BOT\venv\lib\site- 
packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 700, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
```